# How to release Android MediaPlayer?

Tags: android, eclipse

Momentarily I have in LogCat "Mediaplayer error (-19,0)" after repeated plays. So the first time(s) I play my app everything is ok, but after a time the Sound doesn't work anymore.

```
public TextView tw;
MediaPlayer mpButtonKlick;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.app);


    tw = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Text);

    tw.setOnClickListener(this);

    mpButtonKlick = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound);




@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    mpButtonKlick.start();
```

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html

Comment: mediaPlayer.release();
mediaPlayer = null;

Comment: Directly after "mpButtonKlick.start(); ?

Answer (score 1):

you release like this:

```
mpButtonKlick.release();
mpButtonKlick = null;
```

It's good practice to also release the MediaPlayer object when you start playing new media to ensure that there is just one instance running.

```
private void stopMedia(){
    mpButtonKlick.release();
    mpButtonKlick = null;
}
```

and when you call `start()` make sure to first call `stopMedia()`;

```
stopMedia();
mpButtonKlick.start();
```

Comment: Thank You Very Much. Where do I have to put it in the code?

Comment: In the on click handler of your play and stop buttons for your media player? How would you otherwise handle the media player?

Answer (score 1):

Try this one.

```
protected void onStop()
{
    mediaPlayer.release();
    mediaPlayer = null;
}
```

Comment: Thx. It didn't work. My app stopped working with that very soon...?!